# Convert open and close tag into self-close tag in Javasript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I am trying to compare two html files. One file only uses self-close tag if the content is empty. The other one uses a mix of self-close tag and open-close tag. I would like to convert all the open-close tags in the second file to be self-close tags so that the ending tags in the two html files are in the same format.
Is there a simple way to convert open and close tag into self-close tag in javascript?

Example:

`<td style=""></td>` => `<td style="" />`

Comment: When I use self-closing tags, the browser tends to convert them to regular open tags and closing tags, when I view the page in Chrome's Inspect > Elements tab, so even if you found each empty tag set and used javascript to replace them with a self-closing tag in the DOM, I suspect, but not actually tried, that some, if not all, browsers would change them back to an open tag and a close tag.  The best way to do this is to pre-process the file outside the browser and change the tags.  In UNIX/LINUX there are several tools that you can do this with, i.e., sed, but you can do this in VB, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am primarily looking for a way to convert it using Javascript. I don't render the html in the browser. I just use them as raw text and compare the difference. I would like to ignore the closing tag difference during the comparison. @HowardBrown

Answer (score 0):

Try cheerio xmlMode:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(`<td style=""></td>`, {xmlMode: true})
console.log($.html())
// <td style=""/>
```